# Open Email Application in Android

Tags: android, email

I have a textView of text email id, when I click the email id, I want to open a email app which is located in the device, and in the "To" address bar should be filled with the clicked email id.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this will help

```
final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

emailIntent .setType("plain/text");
emailIntent .putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"webmaster@website.com"});
emailIntent .putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, mySubject);
emailIntent .putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, myBodyText);

context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send mail...));
```

stolen from [link](http://www.anddev.org/email_send_intent_intentchooser-t3295.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i want to open a mail box as like our desktop behaves, so that the user can compose the mail and can send or can't send, The behavior is look like same as our desktop application. If u didn't got the point i will explain more about this

Comment: yeah, it should do that. it opens the mail-application, sets the to-address to webmaster@website.com. you can remove the lines with subject and the bodytext.